# bootstrap top nav sub menu links do nothing but right click does

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I inherited this project. It has a navbar fixed to the top of each page and a  bootstrap navbar-brand link on the left top. This works fine.

It also has a side-nav that works and all its dropdown links work.

However, the right top menu items, all dropdowns, do nothing except drop down. Clicking on sub-items do nothing. But if you right click and open in a new tab they work fine.

Also if you enter the link that shows when you hover into the browser, it works.

Here is an example:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ Auth::user()->username }} <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li>
      <a href="{{ action('UsersController@logout') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

bootstrap files come after jQuery files both css and js. All are in the header and even putting js at the end of the body changes nothing.

Here is the head:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>RPM</title>

  <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/rpm/public/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Switch CSS -->
  <link href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap Datepicker CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/datepicker.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap Dropdown CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.css">


  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
  <!--<link href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="http://localhost/rpm/public/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
```

Edit: Yep, it works ok by itself.
here is the entire code with top and side menus:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ action('HomeController@index') }}">RPM</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Top Menu Items -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu message-dropdown">
        <!-- foreach through messages here -->
        <li class="message-preview">
          <a href="#">
            <div class="media">
              <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>{{ Auth::user()->username }}</strong>
                                        </h5>
                <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="message-footer">
          <a href="#">Read All New Messages</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-default">Alert Badge</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-primary">Alert Badge</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-success">Alert Badge</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-info">Alert Badge</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-warning">Alert Badge</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-danger">Alert Badge</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">View All</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ Auth::user()->username }} <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="{{ action('UsersController@logout') }}">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="{{ action('HomeController@index') }}">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reservations">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-text"></i> Reservations
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul id="reservations" class="collapse">
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReservationController@index') }}">Search</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReservationController@create') }}">New reservation</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReservationChargeController@index') }}">Charges</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> Calendar
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{{ action('PropertyController@index') }}">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Properties
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reports">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-area-chart"></i> Reports
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul id="reports" class="collapse">
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@arrivals') }}">Arrivals</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@departures') }}">Departures</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@cancellations') }}">Cancellations</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@daily') }}">Daily</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@deposit') }}">Deposit</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@management') }}">Management</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@owner') }}">Owner</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@rental') }}">Rental</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@summary') }}">Summary</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@tax') }}">Tax</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ReportController@transactions') }}">Transactions</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#management">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-gavel"></i> Management
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul id="management" class="collapse">
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('OwnerController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Owners
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('RateController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dollar"></i> Rates
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('AmenityController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-tags"></i> Amenities
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('ExtrasController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus-square-o"></i> Extras
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('DiscountController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-down"></i> Discounts
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('CleanerController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> Cleaners
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('TaxController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></i> Taxes
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('SourceController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i> Sources
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ action('GuestController@index') }}">
              <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> Guests
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!--<li>
                        <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
                    </li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Even when he gets a JavaScript error the link should work because it's pure HTML.

Comment: Works fine on Bootply, so the error must exist somewhere else in code that you haven't provided. http://www.bootply.com/ygcc2gz6aN

Comment: There are no errors on the console because no action takes place. If you click on the "link" nothing happens. Nothing goes back to the server.

Comment: What an awesome use for the StackSnippets!

Comment: Did you try stepping through the Javascript to see if maybe there is something preventing it from working? In Firebug under the script tab click the 'break on next' button to the left and then try and logout.

Comment: Stepping through the jQuery even listener shows that the click event is getting picked up, but it is making no call, just returns as if a random click was made on the page.

Comment: can you put entire page code plz.